# Always getting an empty string from an input value using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, laravel-blade

I am trying to build a chat module in my website.
I created an input and a button. The input stores the message that is to be sent and the button calls a JavaScript function to send the message using `fetch()`.

I am having trouble obtaining the value of the `input` element which is used to type the message.

Here is an example of the code without using `fetch()` as it is not directly linked to the problem at hand, it's working on the snippets but on my local with Blade, I obtained an empty string from the logging of the input:

```js
function sendMessage() {
    console.log('Send button clicked!');
    var sendButton = document.getElementById('send-button');
    var messageInput = document.getElementById('message-input');
    console.log(messageInput);
    var content = messageInput.value.trim();
    console.log(content)
    if (content !== '') {
        var data = {
            conversation_id: '{{ $conversation->id }}',
            content: content,
            _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}'
        };
        console.log("We are inside of the IF statement!")
    }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="mt-4">
    <div class="flex flex-row items-center">
        <input type="text" id="message-input" class="w-full text-black rounded-lg border-gray-300 border p-2 mr-2" placeholder="Type your message here...">
        <button id="send-button" onclick="sendMessage()" class="bg-blue-500 text-white rounded-lg px-4 py-2 hover:bg-blue-600 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline-blue">
            Send
        </button>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Aside from JavaScript, I have tried to accomplish this using jQuery and other techniques (wrapping the function in a `DOMContentLoaded` block, using a `textarea` instead of `input`, but the value of the input remains an empty string (`""`).

I would also add that `messageInput` is defined - a valid HTML element (`input`).

Edit :
Here is a test that I have made following an advice, adding an event listener to my input, but nothing happened when I entered the input.
The input object is logged, so the problem is not from my query selector

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed");
    const input = document.getElementById('message-input');
    console.log(input);
    input.addEventListener("input", updateValue);

    function updateValue(e) {
        console.log("Input value:", e.target);
    }
});
```

Nb : I already asked this question, but wasn't clear at all, thanks to @Dimitar and @Nico Hase for helping me edit it.

Comment: The entered message seems to be logged fine when clicking Send button. What is your actual issue when obtaining the value?

Comment: Sorry, the Snippets is just here for example, on my local I obtain an empty string

Comment: We can't say what goes wrong without seeing the real code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would check if the real code does not instantiate another element with id 'message-input' after the one you actually want the value.

Comment: Thanks you so much, it was actually that, the mobile display was commented but loaded in the DOM, it works now, thx